# Storing information from ListView Adapter without SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have an adapter that extends BaseAdapter; within are defined two checkboxes.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.apkName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appname);
        holder.category1 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category1);
        holder.category1.setTag(position);
        holder.category2 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category2);
        holder.category2.setTag(position);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) getItem(position);
    Drawable appIcon = packageManager.getApplicationIcon(packageInfo.applicationInfo);
    String appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(packageInfo.applicationInfo).toString();
    appIcon.setBounds(0, 0, 55, 55);
    holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawables(appIcon, null, null, null);
    holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawablePadding(15);
    holder.apkName.setText(appName);
    holder.category1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if(holder.category1.isChecked()){
                holder.2.setChecked(false);
                int getPosition = (Integer) holder.category1.getTag();

            }
        }
    });
    holder.category2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b){
            if(holder.category2.isChecked()){
                holder.category1.setChecked(false);
                int getPosition = (Integer) holder.educational.getTag();
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Basically what I have is a list of all my apps, then the two checkboxes where you can select either one or neither checkbox. As I understand, the getPosition variable will distinguish between the pairs of checkboxes? What I want is to store which checkboxes have been checked by the user. My idea was first to use SharedPreferences and store the boolean value of each getPosition, but SharedPreferences aren't working. Is that because I'm extending a BaseAdapter instead of an Activity? How can I retrieve whether or not a checkbox is checked in my main activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getSharedPreferences(String, int)
```

needs to have a context. You can always pass in a context in your adapter:

```
class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Context context;
public YourAdapter(Context context){
   this.context=context;
}
//What ever u need to do in this adapter
private doStuff(){
   context.getSharedPreferences(String, int);//ok
}
}
```

When you are creating this adapter in your Activity, just pass in the activity like:

```
YourAdapter mAdapter=new YourAdapter (this); //in your activity .
```

Comment: This was helpful, I got the shared preferences working, another quick question though, is the getTag() method the one responsible for distinguishing between the checkboxes in the rows?

Comment: Quick answer. no. View.getId() would be a better option, but this is not related to this question. You should post another if it really is a question that needs an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing it but I don't see where you are trying to use `SharedPreferences` (I do have a bum eye today) but you should be able to use your `Context` that's passed in. As long as you have a valid `Activity Context` use

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(...);
```

Another option, if you don't need it to be persistent and just stored while the user is currently in the app, is to set the values in a `class` with `static` variables to hold the value and retrieve them from there. However, if you want it to be persistent then `SharedPreferences` is the best way to go with this.

Comment: Sorry, didn't have any attempt to put in SharedPrefences in this code just because, the error came up regardless of where I tried to put it in, but this works. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, just wasn't sure if it was there and I missed it. Glad you got it working